# Что делать, если без причины исчез вай фай на ноутбуке с Windows?

Tags: windows, wifi

У меня виндовс 11 и ноутбук ASUS. Скриншот приложить не могу, так как он весит больше 2 мб, а уменьшить его тоже не могу, ведь пишу с телефона. поэтому попытаюсь описать все словами. Я, как обычно, включил ноутбук и Wi-Fi. Открыл панель справа снизу, там где звук, интернет и батарея и увидел, что значка Wi Fi, где можно к нему подключиться нет, и включить его в "Изменить быстрые настройки" нельзя. Раньше (буквально вчера) все было нормально, поэтому проблема вряд ли в устройстве. Что делать?

Comment: Через диспечер устройств удали wi-fi адаптер, только без установки галочки "удалить драйвера", а потом выполни поиск устройств. Поможет?

Answer (score 1):

а карту случайно не выключил комбинацией клавиш? гугли для своей модели ноутбука как включить вай фай карту хоткеями, обычно это fn+клавиша с лого антенны вай фай на клавишах f, а заодно проверить есть ли в диспетчере устройств эта карта в сетевых, может проблема с дровами